# How much time until real time users drop off the Google Analytics real time report after their last hit?

Tags: google-analytics, real-time

In Google Analytics under the "real time analytics", how much time does it take before the report stops tracking the user if no more hits are detected?

I know that if clicks, events or pages are loaded it keeps tracking that user. It waits until that user does nothing on the page to stop showing them.   How much time does it take before Google says that the user is no longer active on the site?

Comment: From memory it's 5 minutes however i cant find the relevant documentation to confirm that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kissmetrics state that Real-Time sessions time out after 5 minutes (unlike the usual 30 minute timeout for sessions) — however their claim is uncited:

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/real-time-reports-google-analytics/

I've seen this claim [elsewhere](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/web-analytics/google-analytics-real-time-wait-no-more) but it's been uncited each time. Hopefully this is not a pervasive myth.

The only similar answer I've found from Google relates to how they define active users on Optimize (rather than Analytics) — [here](https://support.google.com/360suite/optimize/answer/6351584?hl=en):

> The Active users column displays how many visitors have been exposed to each variant in the last five minutes. Users are active for the duration of the session, which times out after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Rhys Mills, I ran a test and looks like it takes around 5 to 6 mins until the real-time user drops-off https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v69CoRb0LYQ.